# jQuery check all checkboxes in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with a checkbox in the table head which I want to use to check/uncheck all the checkboxes in my table. This is my code, but it doesn't work.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#select_products_checkbox', function() {
  $('.form-control').toggleClass('selected');
  var selectAllProductsIsChecked = $('#select_products_checkbox').prop('checked');
  
  $('.form-control .form-control').each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).prop('checked', selectAllProductsIsChecked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" id="select_products_checkbox">
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-1 text-center">{t}Product ID{/t}</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="{$price_list_products_checkbox}[]" value="{$productID}" class="form-control" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        {$productID}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `$('.form-control').toggleClass('selected');` affects both the checkbox in the header and in the body..

Comment: This selector looks wrong - `$('.form-control .form-control')` - maybe $('tbody .form-control')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you pass your event into the change function you can just use the currentTarget checked to set your checked prop on your other checkboxes:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#select_products_checkbox', function(e) {
  $('.form-control')
    .toggleClass('selected', e.currentTarget.checked)
    .prop('checked', e.currentTarget.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" id="select_products_checkbox">
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-1 text-center">{t}Product ID{/t}</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="{$price_list_products_checkbox}[]" value="{$productID}" class="form-control" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        {$productID}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Follow-up question: any idea how to "personalize" each checkbox assigned to a product? I tried <class="form-control-product{$productID}" in the html code and $('#form-control-product') in jQuery but id didn't work

Comment: you would need a common class as well as your custom class so something like `form-control form-control--product-{$productID}` then you can leave your jquery selector for all checkboxes as `.form-control` and if you want to target your specific product you can use `.form-control--product-productID` where productID is replaced by the actual id

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require you can use the `closest()` and `find()` methods to find the checkboxes in the `tbody` of the table related to the 'All' checkbox. Then you can use `prop()` to set their `checked` state to match. Similarly you can provide a boolean to `toggleClass()` to add or remove the class based on whether or not the 'All' was checked.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#select_products_checkbox', function() {  
  $(this).closest('table').find('tbody :checkbox')
    .prop('checked', this.checked)
    .toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" id="select_products_checkbox">
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-1 text-center">{t}Product ID{/t} - SELECT ALL</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="{$price_list_products_checkbox}[]" value="{$productID}" class="form-control" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        {$productID}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="{$price_list_products_checkbox}[]" value="{$productID}" class="form-control" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        {$productID}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="{$price_list_products_checkbox}[]" value="{$productID}" class="form-control" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        {$productID}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="{$price_list_products_checkbox}[]" value="{$productID}" class="form-control" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        {$productID}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="{$price_list_products_checkbox}[]" value="{$productID}" class="form-control" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        {$productID}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```